# importing js module executes css file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm trying to create a single index file that I can import similar modules.

e.g.

```
import { foo } from './random';
// or
import bar from './random';
```

so I have index.js file in `random/`

```
import bar from './bar';
import foo from './foo';

export {
  foo 
};

export default DefaultSurvey;
```

that works great, however I have a minor issue.

`foo.js` extends `bar.js`

```
import './Foo.scss';
export default class Foo extends Bar
```

the problem lies here:

```
import foo from './foo';
```

If I try `import bar from './random';`

the css from `foo.js` applies to the default export., why is that?

Comment: What do you mean by "*the css from foo.js applies to the default export*"? CSS applies to HTML selectors, not to JS module exports.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why is this a problem? Shouldn't all css be loaded? Unless, you want to conditionally load certain css-files, which is another issue.

Maybe I've got this question all wrong, and please correct me if I have, but when you import the default export from `random/`, i.e. `import bar from './random';`, you are also executing all imports in that module i.e. importing all dependencies. Since you are importing `foo from './foo';` in the `random/`-module, and importing the css in `foo.js`, these dependencies will be loaded when referincing the `random/`-module.

To avoid a circular dependency hell, I'd recommend putting all imports of css-files into one file, e.g. the index file. That way you could avoid unexpected behaviour.